# How much does importing entire modules such as wxpython effect the size of the application when built using py2app?

Tags: python, wxpython, py2app

Does using, for example, import TextCrtl from wx make the application smaller when built as a stand alone app?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you import a module, or import something *from* a module, the entire module is always executed. The only difference is what is added to the namespace.

Here's a nice SO answer on this subject: [Does "from-import" exec the whole module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114787/does-from-import-exec-the-whole-module/1115073#1115073)

So the answer is no, the entire module will always be included.